# How to extract named entity recognition tags of the type "b-per", "b-misc" etc using spaCy and Python?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

The documentation I can find suggests using the "labels_" attribute of the spans in a spaCy document. However for me this returns POS tags not NER tags. I need to have types indicating if it begins the NER span ("B" or otherwise "I") and the type of NER tag (e.g. "per" for a person), and otherwise "o" if it is not an NER span.

```
for idx, doc in enumerate(train_docs):
    for ent in doc.ents:
        ner_structured_docs.append([idx, ent.text,ent.label_])
```

this gives the index (i.e. sentence id),because each doc is a separate sentence. It then gives the span (ent). ent.text gives the text of the span correctly. However ent.label_ gives the POS tag (e.g. "NOUN", "DET") not NER tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Accessing entity annotations and labels](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#accessing-ner).

You can also access token entity annotations using the `token.ent_iob_` and `token.ent_type_` attributes. `token.ent_iob_` indicates whether an entity starts, continues or ends on the tag. If no entity type is set on a token, it will return an empty string.

Here is an example:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
res = nlp("I am Tom and I was born in New York")
```

You can either build the IOB tags by yourself:

```
IOB_tags = [
    "-".join(filter(len, (token.ent_iob_, token.ent_type_)))
    for token in res
]
```

or you can use built-in functions ([`biluo_to_iob`](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#biluo_to_iob) and [`offsets_to_biluo_tags`](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#offsets_to_biluo_tags)):

```
from spacy.training import biluo_to_iob, offsets_to_biluo_tags

IOB_tags = biluo_to_iob(
    offsets_to_biluo_tags(
        res,
        [(ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_) for ent in res.ents],
    ),
)
```

In both cases this is the result:

```
['O', 'O', 'B-PERSON', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-GPE', 'I-GPE']
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is for some reason ent_type_ is giving me part of speech tags ("DET", "NOUN", "ADJ" etc) instead of NER tags. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @GRH Please update your question with a *minimal* example (that I can completely reproduce). Without seeing an example with real data I can't help you

Comment: @GRH have you solved your problem? is my answer useful?